# MySQL RDS replication dies with a LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, replication, rds

I am having a baffling problem with a simple RDS read replica, where when we do a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on the master, it kills the read replica reliably with :

```
Error 'Access denied for user ''@'' (using password: NO)' on query. Default database: 'testdb'. Query: 'LOAD DATA INFILE '/rdsdbdata/tmp/SQL_LOAD-5ce65f0d-1a6a-11e3-af1b-12313c014074-352397698-1549.data' IGNORE INTO  TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`name`, `age`)'
```

To replicate the situation, I had a simple master and create a table called test:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It was replicated to the read replica successfully.  Then i setup my input file :

```
# cat test.csv
steve,24
bob,34
courtney,12
ben,28
aidan,15
```

Then imported it with (Ignore the warnings, i didnt get my separator right but data went in) :

```
mysqlimport --local testdb test.csv
testdb.test: Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 5
```

And that's all it takes to kill the read replica.  I'm connecting to mysql as the user you create when you make the RDS instance, so it should have all permissions.  But regardless, the read replica would have its own replication user.   I've tried making the read-replicate NOT read-only, and this didn't seem to work.

```
mysql> status;
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.27, for FreeBSD9.0 (amd64) using  5.2

Connection id:          13481
Current database:       testdb
Current user:           testuser@ip-10-50-99-59.eu-west-1.compute.internal
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          more
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.13-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             saturn.xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 8 hours 52 min 23 sec

Threads: 3  Questions: 775195  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 51017  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 2000  Queries per second avg: 24.268
```

Would love if anyone could help

thanks

Steve

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I just ran into the same problem (though we're using MySQL 5.5.33)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this breaks is essentially because the read replica is replaying the binary logs and when it gets to your LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement, it doesn't have that file.

RDS Creates a brand new read replica from an existing database by using a snapshot, not by replaying the bin logs.

So the solution is: after any LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is executed against the master you will have to delete your read replica and re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS technical support, this is a known issue when importing a CSV via LOAD DATA INFILE.

For me, issuing the following command caused the read replica to skip the error and sync successfully:

```
CALL mysql.rds_skip_repl_error;
```

There was no need to delete and re-create the read replica.

Update: This issue resolved itself when I upgraded the read replica to MySQL 5.6.